# Shell Scripting to read every single files within a folder with a particular start and extension

Tags: bash, shell

I am very new to shell scripting. I have a folder containing files with sequential name, e.g.

```
ABC19001_1_good_(another random 4 characters or numbers).txt
ABC19001_1_good_notsoideal_(another random 4 characters or numbers).txt
ABC19001_2_good_(another random 4 characters or numbers).txt
ABC19001_2_good_notsoideal_(another random 4 characters or numbers).txt
ABC19002_1_good_(another random 4 characters or numbers).txt
...
```

Is there a way to specify only reading the `ABCxxxxx_x_good_(another random 4 characters or numbers).txt` without reading those containing the `notsoideal` string within a shell script (similar idea to using the regular expression in python)?

Thank you for your kind assistance.

I tried `$ABC19*.txt` and it includes all files.
I tried `$ABC19*good_*{4}.txt` to filter out the `notsoideal` file but this doesn't work.

Comment: Probably `ABC?????_?_good_????.txt` or `ABC[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]_[0-9]_good_????.txt`.

Comment: An obscure shell globing feature found in `ksh` and `bash` is `/bin/ls ABC1900!(*notsoideal*)` which produces output of `ABC19001_1_good_76543.txt  ABC19001_2_good_76543.txt  ABC19002_1_good_76543.txt` from the sample file names I morphed from your sample files. The feature is `file!(notMatchPattern)` (the exclamation point and parenthized non-glob-match) . For future question writing, please don't including spaces and parens in filenames, unless that is a key part of your problem. (However, you'll find that this works with your filenames too). Good luck.

Comment: Thank you guys. Got it sorted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program for each of the 2 specific scenarios:

- include "*good*", and
- exclude "notsoideal"

So ...

```
ls AB19* | grep '_good_' | grep -v 'notsoideal'
```

**Script** offering selective capture/printing of items according to option **--selector ${value}** :

```
#!/bin/bash

dodemo=0
mode=1

while [ $# -gt 0 ]
do
    case $1 in
        --demo ) dodemo=1 ; shift ;;
        --file ) rawlist="${2}" ; shift ; shift ;;
        --selector ) selector="${2}" ; mode=2 ; shift ; shift ;;
    esac
done

if [ -z "${rawlist}" ]
then
    dodemo=1
fi

if [ ${dodemo} -eq 1 ]
then
    rawlist="list_raw.txt"
    cat >"${rawlist}" <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
ABC19001_1_good_AnotherRandomFourCharactersOrNumbers.txt
ABC19001_2_good_AnotherRandomFourCharactersOrNumbers.txt
ABC19002_1_good_AnotherRandomFourCharactersOrNumbers.txt
ABC19002_2_good_AnotherRandomFourCharactersOrNumbers.txt
ABC19003_1_good_AnotherRandomFourCharactersOrNumbers.txt
ABC19003_2_good_AnotherRandomFourCharactersOrNumbers.txt
ABC19004_1_good_AnotherRandomFourCharactersOrNumbers.txt
ABC19004_2_good_AnotherRandomFourCharactersOrNumbers.txt
ABC19005_1_good_AnotherRandomFourCharactersOrNumbers.txt
ABC19005_2_good_AnotherRandomFourCharactersOrNumbers.txt
EnDoFiNpUt
fi

if [ ! -s "${rawlist}" ]
then
    echo "Unable to proceed.  Empty file list provided as parameter."
    exit 1
fi


index=0

for prefix in $(cut -f1 -d\_ "${rawlist}" | uniq)
do
    case ${mode} in
        1 )
            ### All elements with shared prefix
            val=$( grep '^'${prefix} "${rawlist}" |
                awk '{
                    if( NR == 1 ){
                        printf("%s", $0 ) ;
                    }else{
                        printf("|%s\n", $0 ) ;
                    } ;
                }' )
            ;;
        2) 
            ### ONLY elements with specified selector
            val=$( grep '^'${prefix} "${rawlist}" | grep "_${selector}_" )
            ;;
    esac

    if [ ${dodemo} -eq 1 ]
    then
        echo -e "\t [${index}] val = ${val} ..."
    fi

    file_array[${index}]="${val}"
    index=$((index+=1))
done

if [ ${dodemo} -eq 1 ]
then
    echo ""
fi
printf "\"%s\"\n" "${file_array[@]}"
```

Comment: Hello. After listing the names, is there a way where i can sort and store them in an array then feed the _1_ and _2_ separately into argument of a function in bash? thank you

Comment: Can you expand on what you want to do with the 1 and 2 ?  Those values could be parsed so that the filenames could be assigned to different arrays (for each of 1 and 2) or one array, where both filenames are captured in a single array element (with a divider between).

Comment: file_1 is forward read of a paired sequence while file_2 is the complementary sequence. When i am feeding them into a function file_1 must be paired with file_2, i.e. as two separate arguments of a function.i.e. STAR input1=ABC001_1_????.txt input1=ABC001_2_????.txt

Comment: Then i can loop over the list or something and feed ABC001, ABC002, ABC003 sequentially after the previous one has been completed.

Answer (score 0):

The filename patterns supported by Bash (and other Bourne-derived shells) are not regular expressions.  They are called "glob" patterns.  See [glob - Greg's Wiki](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob) for detailed information about them.  The definitive reference for glob patterns is the [Pattern Matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) section of the [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html).

A possible glob pattern to do what you want is:

```
ABC19*good_????.txt
```

There are two problems with `$ABC19*good_*{4}.txt`.  First, the `$` will cause an attempted expansion of a variable called `ABC19`.  That will probably expand to nothing, so the pattern will be equivalent to `*good_*{4}.txt`.  Second, `{` and `}` have no special significance in glob patterns.  The pattern matches filenames that contain `good_` and end with the literal string `{4}.txt`.  Some, but not all, regular expression dialects support `{...}` patterns.  In those dialects `.{4}` (or in some `.\{4\}`) matches any 4 characters.